# find every nth. max in a data frame and the belonging information

Tags: r, max

I have a data frame that looks the following:

```
    ID      A    weekday Walking
   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1  40001      1     1       3.1
2  40001      1     2       5.2
3  40001      1     3       6
4  40001      1     4       9.0
5  40001      1     5       11
6  40001      1     6       0.4
7  40001      1     7       2
8  40002      2     1       4.9
9  40002      2     2       11
10 40002      2     3       20.1
11 40002      2     4       1
12 40002      2     5       4
13 40002      2     6       4
14 40002      2     7       5
```

My data frame has a bout 1500 rows.

I want to get the max of every 7th row in the column walking.
I did this by using the following:

```
cbind(rollapply(data$Walking,7,max,by=7))
```

for example the max would be:
for the first ID: 9.0 and
for the second ID: 20.1

However what I need is something like this:

```
ID     weekday Walking
40001    4       9.0
40002    3       20.1
```

So I basically need every belonging information in the row with the maximum.

I am happy for every help

Thank you

Comment: I noticed there are 7 rows for each is, can you group by ID instead? E.g. `data %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(Walking == max(Walking))`

Comment: Why is one of your example max values `40001, 4, 9.0` instead of `40001, 5, 11`?

Comment: Try `df %>% group_by(ID) %>% slice_max(Walking, n = 1)`

Comment: thank you, @MartinGal, your are right, I made a mistake

Answer (score 1):

If you can't group by `ID` and your data is grouped into 7 item blocks, you can create a dummy index and use it for grouping:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  group_by(idx=rep(1:(ceiling(nrow(.)/7)), each=7)[1:nrow(.)])%>% 
  slice_max(Walking)
```

But usally @mhovd's and @KarthikS's solution should solve your problem.